# How can I change a picture in word using drag and drop

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Is it possible to change a picture in word with drag and drop? In other words, dragging a picture from windows explorer onto an existing picture in word?

Having to right-click on a picture selecting "Change picture" and then browsing for it is not very efficient.

*Edit* 
Apparently this is easy to do in Word 2016
I am interested if/how it is possible to do that in Word 2013.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? If the functionality isn't there then it isn't there... And your quesion seems to be explicitly about drag and drop so not sure what other option there is, unless you write some custom vba event for this... :(

Comment: I did try it, but sometimes there is a little trick to make things work, e.g. ctrl-alt-drop or something, or some option I haven't seen.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in Word 2016 :

1. Click to select the image to be replaced
2. Drag-and-drop the image onto the page
3. The new image replaces the selected one